# Dropdowmenu: Align submenus to their parents dynamically with JQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

I have a dropdown menu where what i want to do is to change the padding left of the submenu dynamically so the parent and the sibling (the submenu) are aligned vertically.

This is the HTML:

```
<nav class="secondary-menu">
<ul class="menu nav navbar-nav secondary">
    <li class="first expanded dropdown">
        <a href="/en/masters-of-science" class="dropdown-toggle">MASTER OF SCIENCE</a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li class="first leaf"><a href="#">Clone of Master of Science in IT Strategic Management</a></li>
            <li class="leaf"><a href="#">Master of Science in Finance and Banking</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="first expanded dropdown">
        <a href="/en/masters-of-science" class="dropdown-toggle">MASTER OF SCIENCE</a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li class="first leaf"><a href="#">Clone of Master of Science in IT Strategic Management</a></li>
            <li class="leaf"><a href="#">Master of Science in Finance and Banking</a></li>
            <li class="first leaf"><a href="#">Clone of Master of Science in IT Strategic Management</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="first expanded dropdown">
        <a href="/en/masters-of-science" class="dropdown-toggle">MASTER OF SCIENCE</a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li class="first leaf"><a href="#">Clone of Master of Science in IT Strategic Management</a></li>
            <li class="leaf"><a href="#">Master of Science in Finance and Banking</a></li>
            <li class="first leaf"><a href="#">Clone of Master of Science in IT Strategic Management</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="first expanded dropdown">
        <a href="/en/masters-of-science" class="dropdown-toggle">MASTER OF SCIENCE</a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li class="first leaf"><a href="#">Clone of Master of Science in IT Strategic Management</a></li>
            <li class="leaf"><a href="#">Master of Science in Finance and Banking</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

So what i'm trying to do is to vertical align all the submenus (ul.dropdown-menu) with their parents (li.dropdown), the general dropdown is already done and working fine i just want to align the elements dynamically.

I have been trying this approach but is not working for me, this script just add the same padding-left to all the submenus :

```
   function submenu_position() {
    var liElements = new Array();
    var count = 0;
    $.each($("#navbar .secondary li"), function () {
        liElements[count] = $(this).width();
        count++;
    });

    $(".secondary .dropdown-menu").css("paddingLeft",    liElements[0]+liElements[1]);

}
```

thanks a lot !

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Solution for your case:**

Add this in your CSS:

```
.navbar-nav .dropdown {position: relative;}
.navbar-nav .dropdown .dropdown-menu {position: absolute; left: 0;}
```

And remove all the JavaScript for `.padding`.

**Updated jQuery Version:**

```
$("head").append('<style>.navbar-nav .dropdown {position: relative;} .navbar-nav .dropdown .dropdown-menu {position: absolute; left: 0;}</style>');
```

---

**Alternate Solution**

You can make the menus display just using **pure CSS**, while you can make the changes in the menu using JavaScript. Would you like to try this?

#### HTML

```
<ul class="nav">
    <li>
        <a href="#">Menu 1</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Menu Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Menu Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Menu Item</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Menu 2</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Menu Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Menu Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Menu Item</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Menu 3</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Menu Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Menu Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Menu Item</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

#### CSS

```
* {font-family: "Segoe UI", Tahoma;}
ul.nav {border-bottom: 1px solid #999;}
ul.nav li a {display: block; text-decoration: none; color: #333; padding: 5px; border: 1px solid #fff;}
ul.nav > li:hover {border: 1px solid #666; border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;}
ul.nav li a:hover {background: #ccc; border: 1px solid #999;}
ul.nav > li {display: inline-block; position: relative; border: 1px solid #fff;}
ul.nav > li ul {display: none; position: absolute; left: -1px; width: 150px; border: 1px solid #666; border-top-color: #fff; margin-top: 1px;}
ul.nav > li:hover ul {display: block;}
ul.nav > li ul li {display: block;} /* Vertical Menu */
ul.nav > li ul li {display: inline-block;} /* Horizontal Menu */
```

#### Fiddle:
 http://jsfiddle.net/vMuxA/ (Vertical Menu)
 http://jsfiddle.net/vMuxA/1/ (Horizontal Menu)

Comment: thanks @Praveen the thing is im working on a drupal site where everything is already done and i cant change the dropdown structure, so i just want to use jquery to vertically align the submenus with the parent li.

Comment: yeah that works but (and im sorry to be hard head here) i really need to this via jquery since there are a lot of design issues that i can't change, in this case for example there's a div that contains the submenus that have to be 100% wide, when i change .navbar-nav .dropdown to relative the width of that div will only have the parent li width.

Comment: You are just adding the css via jquery there, check the image i have added, if i apply that css the white background there will not take the 100% of the parent navbar just the parent li width. What i need to do is to align all those subitems to their parent li and changing the css is not an option im afraid at least not doing what you are telling me here.